# MySQL skipping auto_increment values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, auto-increment

In my users table there are only 3 fields

```
id (primary key, auto increment), 
username (not null, unique) and 
password(not null).
```

When I tried to insert a row with values "test" and "123" I got 1 as the primary key and then I tried again with the same value and I got duplicate entry for key "username" as expected and then i tried with "test1" and "123" and I got 3 as the primary key, 2 is skipped, why it is showing this behavior.

MySQL version is 5.7.27.

Comment: Please provide the defintion of the table. if all constraints are ok and INSERT is failing, you can use REPLACE instead of INSERT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [documented behavior](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html):

> “Lost” auto-increment values and sequence gaps
>
> In all lock modes (0, 1, and 2), if a transaction that generated auto-increment values rolls back, those auto-increment values are “lost”. Once a value is generated for an auto-increment column, it cannot be rolled back, whether or not the “INSERT-like” statement is completed, and whether or not the containing transaction is rolled back. Such lost values are not reused. Thus, there may be gaps in the values stored in an AUTO_INCREMENT column of a table.

In your use case,  the auto_increment is assigned a new value before the unique constraint on `username` is checked. Then the constraint check fails and the transaction is rolled back, leaving a gap in the sequence.

There are various other cases than can lead to gaps in the auto_increment sequence (eg when using the `INSERT ... IGNORE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax), that are in essence related to an implicit or explicit rollback of the transaction.

Bottom line: **do not assume that aut_increment keys are sequential**. What is guaranteed is uniqueness, and, to some extent, increasing numbers.

Comment: @Sony, to add to the bottom line mentioned by GMB, also do not try into *"fixing"* your auto_increment to be sequential, that is also a big no no as bugs/problems like  hard to debug race conditions can happen then..